# What is the meaning of this AS (Action Script code)

Tags: flash, encryption, actionscript

I'm confused with this since i'm not an AS expert

```
while (var6 < (var5 - 1))  
{
 var8 = var3[(var6 + 1)];  
 var10 = (var7 >>> 5 ^ var8 << 2) + (var8 >>> 3 ^ var7 << 4) ^ (var13 ^ var8) + (var4[var6   & 3 ^ var11] ^ var7);  
 var var14:* = var3[var6] + var10;  
 var3[var6] = var3[var6] + var10;  
 var7 = var14;  
 var6 = var6 + 1;  
}
```

What i want to know exactly is what is the meaning of these operators:

1. `>>>` and `^`
2. `(var8 >>> 3 ^ var7 << 4)`
3. `var11 = var13 >>> 2 & 3`

Answer (score 5):

These are all known as bitwise operators, i.e. operators that manipulate integer values by their binary representations. You can find a full reference of operators in ActionScript [in Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html).

`>>>` is the [bitwise unsigned right shift](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#bitwise_unsigned_right_shift) operator; it shifts bits to the right without preserving the sign of a value.

`^` is the [bitwise XOR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#bitwise_XOR) operator. It takes two operands and performs a XOR operation on their bits.

The expression `(var8 >>> 3 ^ var7 << 4)` means:

1. `var8` bit-shifted 3 times to the right (divided by 2^3);
2. result bitwise XORed with `var7`;
3. result bit-shifted 4 times to the left (multiplied by 2^4).

And the expression `var11 = var13 >>> 2 & 3` means:

1. `var13` bit-shifted 2 times to the right (divided by 2^2);
2. result [bitwise AND](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#bitwise_AND)ed with `3`;
3. assigned to `var11`.

Comment: Thank you BoltClock for you help. I steal have a small question what is the difference between >> and >>> technically.

Comment: @Zarboot: `>>` preserves the sign; i.e. `-8 >> 1` would give you `-4` with the negative sign, but `-8 >>> 1` would give you a different result because it doesn't preserve the sign bit (the leftmost bit). See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Comment: You can mark an answer accepted by clicking the checkmark on the left. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 0):

It's doing bitwise math http://www.moock.org/asdg/technotes/bitwise.

Answer (score 0):

Looks decompiled to me... it's hard to imagine someone who can surely tell the operator precedence of `&` and `^` and on the other hand using `i = i + 1` / untyped variables... Since there are like 15 of the variables, it feels like it's the MD5 algorithm... don't know why are you decompiling it, if that's the case...

So, you will also need this very much to understand it: operators [precedense and associativity](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7fd1.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f6c)

Comment: indeed it is. I found this on the net, but i was wondering what is the meaning of all these operators. And yes it's part of the TEA implementation. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It is part of an implementation of [XXTEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XXTEA).

XXTEA by definition works with unsigned integers.
Hence the implementation must use unsigned right shift operators (i.e. >>> but not >>).
Left shifts (<<) do not depend on whether the integesrs are signed or not.